# Subquery returns more than 1 row / Exponential Moving average

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

```
CREATE DEFINER = `ninja_dba`@`` PROCEDURE `adb`.`MACD12`( x int)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

MACD_12:BEGIN
DECLARE z FLOAT;  
DECLARE y FLOAT default 56.41;
DECLARE w float;

WHILE x < 10 do
INSERT  into `MACD`(
x,y,z,X12) select z,y,x,w;

SET  z= IFNULL ( (y + ((2/13) * (w - y))),Y) ;
SET y=z;
SET x =x+1;
SET w = (select close from`raw data`);

end while;

end MACD_12;

END

call macd12 (1);
```

I'm trying to construct a Exponential moving Average. Part of the problem is setting the first row, hence I declare the first row (56.41) as the procedure begins.  I believe the procedure will work, however when I try to call the procedure, I get the infamous error "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error 1242.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies with

```
SET w = (select close from`raw data`);
```

It would seem that `raw data` has more that 1 row, and this is where the error is likely to occur.

You need to either specify a criteria (`WHERE` clause), or use a `LIMIT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a LIMIT 1 on the end of

```
SET w = (select close from`raw data`);
```

Does it work without errors?

Comment: With a limit of 1 I get no errors. Adjust the limit anything greater than 1 and I get: Subquery returns more than 1 row